# How to get all combinations of a list without repeated elements?

Tags: r

I have a list with 40,000 elements, only 16 of which are unique but are all differently weighted.

```
    letters = letters[1:16]
    freq=c(8221, 6717, 4912, 3810, 3409, 2807, 2607, 2406, 2206, 1203,  501,  401,  301,  201,  201,  100)
    list = rep(letters,freq)
```

I'm trying to get 10,000 combinations of 4 from this list (exhausting every letter in the list) but the catch is that no letter can be repeated within each permutation. Combos can be repeated ('ABCD' might appear more than once), but the same letter cannot appear in a combo ('AABC' or 'FFGH' should not count).

Alternatively, I have tried working with this as a data frame with the letter and the frequency as variables, as opposed to the giant list I had above.

```
    letters = letters[1:16]
    freq=c(8221, 6717, 4912, 3810, 3409, 2807, 2607, 2406, 2206, 1203,  501,  401,  301,  201,  201,  100)
    df = data.frame(letters,freq)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: quick question: how are you going to get `10000` combinations of 4 distinct letters out of 16  if `choose(16,4) = 1820`? Maybe I do not understand the question....

Comment: It's because combos can be repeated. Since letters  have frequencies, we know how many times each one will appear. So there are 40,000 possible letters and I'm trying to make 10,000 combos of 4, some of which will repeat.

Comment: I understand now, thanks. Check the answer I provided.

Comment: `list = rep(letters,freq)` defines a *vector* rather than a list, so in that sense your notation is confusing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'exhausting every letter in the list' but one approach might be to use the `freq` variable as a probability weight with `sample()` - `replicate(10000, sample(letters[1:16], 4, replace = FALSE, prob = freq/sum(freq)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you sample, you can specify the probabilities

```
    freq=c(8221, 6717, 4912, 3810, 3409, 2807, 2607, 2406, 2206, 1203,  501,  401,  301,  201,  201,  100)

    COMBI = lapply(1:10000,function(i){
sample(letters[1:16],4,prob=freq/sum(freq),replace=F)
})
table(sapply(COMBI,function(i)length(unique(i))))
```

Comment: Actually, on further inspection, it didn't work. It was duping a lot of the letters (AAAA was observed). I don't want to have any dupes.

Comment: hmmm, ok i updated my code, you can check the number of unique, it's all 4.

Comment: The only issue now is that the frequencies are not matching (a is showing up 6697 times instead of 8221).

Comment: In your original answer, about 8300/10000 rows didn't have a duplicate. I checked the frequencies on just those 8300 rows and they did match the original frequencies on a proportional basis. Wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but for all intents and purposes it got me close enough. If you'd like to keep poking at this with me, then I appreciate your effort. I thank you for your help today!

Comment: table(unlist(lapply(1:1000,function(i)sample(letters[1:16],4,prob=freq/sum(freq),replace=T))))["a"], this gives you ~ 800/1000

Comment: So your assumptions for the frequency of 'a' only holds for, with replacement. When you sample without, it's more complicated. And I showed you proof there's no duplicate.